# jQuery: can't get the value of element

Tags: jquery, spring-boot

I can't get the value of the element in spring boot template, my template:

```js
$("#article-list .list-item").click(function() {
  console.log($("#test").val());
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#article-list").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <body>
    <ul id="article-list">
      <h1 id="test">this is the test content</h1>
      <li class="list-item">
        <h2 class="article-title">title</h2>
        <p class="article-excerpt">content</p>
        <span class="article-time">2017-12-22</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list-item">
        <h2 class="article-title">title</h2>
        <p class="article-excerpt">content</p>
        <span class="article-time">2017-12-22</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The value of `h1` always null, I can't get it. And, I've tested the `jQuery`, it works. Using jQuery to change the `ul` element background color, it's ok. Like this:

But I can't get the value of `h1`

Comment: You can not use `val()` method to get the text for HTML element for that you need to use `text()` or `html()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `.val()` to get the content of the `h1` that is for input and select elements. Use `.text()` or `.html()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="article-list">
    <h1 id="test">this is the test content</h1>
    <li class="list-item">
        <h2 class="article-title">title</h2>
        <p class="article-excerpt">content</p>
        <span class="article-time">2017-12-22</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <h2 class="article-title">title</h2>
        <p class="article-excerpt">content</p>
        <span class="article-time">2017-12-22</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#article-list .list-item").click(function() {
        console.log($("#test").text());
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And `textarea` elements.

Comment: * for forms elements (input, progressbar, textarea and several other goodies )